# Is Mr. Eko a mispronunciation of Mistereko?

Tags: character, lost

On Netflix, *Lost* Season 2 Episode 5 ("...And Found"), with the subtitles turned on, when sawyer asks Mr. Eko what his name is he says "Mistereko" in the subtitles. Sawyer looks bewildered and responds "Mr. Eko?" To me, it looks like Eko has some amusement with this hick pronunciation of his name, and smiles and responds "Yes."

Could Mr. Eko be actually be a mispronunciation of the a legit sounding name Mistereko? If you look this up all it says is that the actor added Mr. onto the name Eko and that:

> I've had some difficulty trying to establish the character with the
>   writers. Y'know, because we were trying to marry what they wanted to
>   do with the show and feelings that I wanted to see come out in the
>   character.

Or...is it just the subtitles messing up?

Comment: [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0411008/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) has him listed as Mr Eko...so it's more likely that this is a subtitle error.

Answer (score 5):

It's [Mr. Eko](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Eko#Childhood):

> Eko and Yemi were separated when Eko shot an unarmed man at the behest
>   of unidentified Nigerian guerrilla members. He did this to spare his
>   brother from having to do so. As a result, Eko was recruited into the
>   guerrilla group instead. When asked his name, he responded "**Eko**."
>   One of the militia members then referred to him as "**Mr. Eko**," a
>   nickname which stuck.